# How to create a remote repository on GitHub that has the same name as local repository

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am just getting used to GitHub from the instructions I got as a beginner, and got stuck at the step below. I am wondering how to get the name of the local repo to be able to create remote repo with same name. So far, I have run: a) git init b) git add readme, c)git commit -m "first". In my directory, I see a .git directory, but don't know the name of the local repo.Thank you.

1. Create a remote repository on GitHub that has the same name as
   your local repository.
2. Add the remote repository (origin) URL to local repository.
3. Push local repostiory to GitHub.
4. Create a local branch, create/add/commit a new file.
5. Merge new local branch commit(s) into local master.
6. Push updated master branch to GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I assume you have your local git already created, if not you will have to do this on the terminal in the directory of your project:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Next in your github account create a new repo:
[An image of how to create a repo on GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGxVr.png)

Then you go to de button that says "clone or download" and copy the link you wish (https or SSH) something like this `https://github.com/YourUsername/YourRepo.git`

And by the end on the console you do this:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/YourUsername/YourRepo.git
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

You can name your remote repo on GitHub anything you want. People just usually name it the same as the folder they are working in, assuming that is the name of their project.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT-Credit to @ dwilbank in the comments for this.

You can create a project/repository on GitHub from the command line, but only if want to install the "hub" utility. Turns out it's actually super useful, but, since your new, I would highly recommend doing it the regular, manual way first before installing bash aliases to extend functionality.  Here's the link to the "hub" utility:  https://github.com/github/hub

From the man page (note this is only **AFTER** installing "hub"):

```
git create [NAME] [-p] [-d DESCRIPTION] [-h HOMEPAGE]
Create a new public GitHub repository from the current git repository 
and add remote origin at "git@github.com:USER/REPOSITORY.git"; USER is 
your GitHub username and REPOSITORY is the current working directory 
name. To explicitly name the new repository, pass in NAME, optionally 
in ORGANIZATION/NAME form to create under an organization you're a 
member of. With -p, create a private repository, and with -d and -h 
set the repository's description and homepage URL, respectively.
```

Normally, through vanilla git, you can't do this.  You need to have a project to push to first.  However, you can just name the project whatever you want, and then just push to it.  The name of the repository doesn't matter (ie, if you upload the "Foo" repo, you can change the folder name and it won't affect the remote repo and vice versa).  All that matters is what's inside your repo, not what it's called.

**Try the following:**

1. Get the url for the reporistory.
   [image: picture of where to get repo url]
2. `git remote add origin "remote repository URL"`
   That should tell your repo where you are pushing to.
3. `git remote -v` Verifies that it's a valid remote address.
4. `git push origin master` Push the commit you made and make sure it shows up on your repo.

Comment: also... once you learn the manual method described above, you can install 'hub', set an alias in your bash init file saying hub=git, and from that day forward, you can type 'git create foo', and a repo will be created on github named 'foo', with the origin automatically added to your local repo.